# Leaving password blank in edit-mode zend

Tags: frameworks, passwords, zend-framework2, edit, validation

is it possible to set the following options:

When you have to add a user, you need to set a password, but when you go and edit a user, then it's not necessary to set a password.

But when you leave your password blank in the edit-mode. It should not overwrite the excisting password.

How can i fix this in Zend framework 2.0?

Edit:

Maybe it's better to show some code.. I've the following validator set on my passwordfields:

```
            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'password',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
            'validators' => array( array(
                    'name' => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 4,
                        'max' => 30,
                    ),
                ), ),
        )));

        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'confirm_password',
            'required' => false,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 4,
                        'max' => 30,
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'identical',
                    'options' => array('token' => 'password')
                ),
            ),
        )));
```

Works fine, but not when i leave it empty in my edit-mode. But it's required in my add-mode. How can i accept empty passwordfields in my edit-mode, without clearing the excisting password of that user?

Answer (score 0):

why not just have a password required bool that is passed into the validation method, using that in conjunction with your current validation rules means it will run the validation if needed. The controller could also detect whether the post/get value from that page as been set and change that bool value accordingly.

Its not the best method and there may be some fancy Zend way of doing this, but the manual won't cover it lol

Example

```
public function validate($passRequired = false)
{
    if ($passRequired) {
        //now run the validation
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I want. I've to set my password required to true when it's in add mode. And false in edit-mode.. Password can allready be empty without overwrite the current pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```html
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
  $form->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());

  if ($form->get("password")->getValue() == ""){
    $form->getInputFilter()->remove('password');
    $form->getInputFilter()->remove('password_r');
  }  

  if ($form->isValid()) {
     // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```